# Windows 10 updates always fail

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, updates

It's been at least one year since my Windows 10 computer always goes on error while manually trying to download new Windows Updates:

[image]

Trying again ("Riprova") doesn't work.
I searched the web but I cannot find a real cause for the error 0x80d05011.
I also tried to manually download some updates from https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/, but with no luck.

Any suggestion?

My device specs:

```
Nome dispositivo    xxxx
Nome completo del dispositivo   xxxx.yyyyyyy.LOCAL
Processore  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7567U CPU @ 3.50GHz   3.50 GHz
RAM installata  32,0 GB (31,9 GB utilizzabile)
ID dispositivo  EF3E3136-E281-4A50-xxxx-82DBB906EF33
ID prodotto 00330-xxxx8-94943-xxxxM
Tipo sistema    Sistema operativo a 64 bit, processore basato su x64
Penna e tocco   Nessun input penna o tocco disponibile per questo schermo
```

My Windows' specs:

```
Edizione    Windows 10 Pro
Versione    21H2
Data installazione: ‎11/‎06/‎2020
Build sistema operativo 19044.1415
Esperienza  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0
```

Answer (score 1):

> It's been at least one year since my Windows 10 computer always goes
> on error while manually trying to download new Windows Updates:

A year is too long to try small recent ideas.

At this point, you need to do a Windows 10 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

Use the option to Keep Everything to begin with. That will usually (but not always) work.

See if Keep Everything works for you.

The remaining two options (Keep only Data and then Keep Nothing) are much more aggressive.

Comment: thank you very much John, I will try your solution but I need some time because this is a development machine and I don't want to mess it up too much...